# How do you prune a rose bush?

Tags: roses, pruning, plant-care

I tried to prune a rose bush and it stopped growing from all the branches I pruned, and instead shot one big green stem up from the root again.  What is the proper technique?

Comment: How short did you prune it? Too close to the root and the branch will "die off".

Comment: The "green stem up from the root" sounds like a sucker and needs would need to be removed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

We only have one rose and it was already planted when we moved in, so practical experience is limited and initial shape left something to be desired. However, I followed the advice in **Neil Sperry's Complete Guide to Texas Gardening** and this seems to work. It is a bit of a traditional gardening book, and a bit proscriptional ("there is only one way and it is this"), but his pruning advice for peaches also seems successful (so far!).

Anyway, he notes:

- they only bloom on new growth
- late winter is best, especially for the bush types. This maximizes new growth in time for spring
- prune climbers after their first spring blooms. The exception are the always blooming types  which should be pruned lightly in winter.
- bush roses should be pruned back 50% and no more

  - remove all weak non-productive canes
  - prune strong canes by 50%, cut just above the buds that face away from the centers of the plants
  - seal cut ends with shellac or white glue (NOT black pruning sealant)

Looking at all that advice I might have half followed it. We've had more die back - perhaps I pruned too much (more than 50% some years): it sounds like you may have made the same mistake.

Also we've had more flowers when I haven't pruned - pruning every other year seems to be working well for us. I think this is because there's more new growth when I haven't pruned, because pruning will always remove new growth.

I've never sealed the ends (and can you even get shellac any more?) - disease might also account for die-back.

The following articles may also prove helpful & worth your while having a reading through:

- [Roses: Care After Planting](http://extension.missouri.edu/p/G6601) from University of Missouri Extension Office
- [Pruning](http://extension.missouri.edu/p/G6601#Pruning) from University of Missouri Extension Office
- Video: [Well-managed Shrub Roses](http://web.extension.uiuc.edu/podcasts/gc/201105_812.html) from University of Illinois Extension
- Video: [How to Prune Roses](http://web.extension.uiuc.edu/podcasts/gc/200909_515.html) from University of Illinois Extension

Comment: sealing ends (cuts) is considered very "old school" & is no longer recommended. You most definitely can still get shellac, it's often used as a finish in fine woodworking...

Comment: Although the book isn't that old it does have traditional outlook - proscriptional and no mention of organic approaches. You also see shellac references in old modelling books, but in the modelling world it has been long replaced by various varnishes.