# How to prune roses with tall branches?

Tags: pruning, roses

I have this neglected rose bush in my garden. It seems too long and spindly? How and when should I prune it?

[image]

Comment: for reference see this question http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/43/how-do-you-prune-a-rose-bush

Comment: Just as a side note, when posting real photos you may want to blur out license plate numbers.

Comment: @JonH  Why?  My license plate is publicly visible to anyone on the street.  Is it somehow more dangerous to have it visible in a photo?

Comment: @chris - chris, my post was in regards to someone else who would not want their license plate visible.  I know that plates are of public domain (in most countries) my point was you can actually be liable for posting someone else's plate if they were to somehow use that in any shape or form.

Answer (score 5):

Pruning for this rose bush should be done in early spring or late fall.  Roses seem to respond well to pruning so either would work.

Prune at an angle and follow each rose down to the base of the long stem. Cut about 1/4 inch away from the main trunk. Be mindful of any new budding stems, if the stem looks like it is budding its best to skip that stem.